# Bash substitution giving basename with one leading directory component

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, dirname

For GNU Screen titling purposes, I'd like to get ahold of the current directory name prefixed by the name of its parent.  For example, within directories

```
/home/rhys/share/pkgconfig
/home/rhys
/home
/
```

producing outputs

```
share/pkgconfig
home/rhys
home
/
```

In Bash, starting from a guess like

```
echo $(basename $(dirname $PWD))/$(basename $PWD)
```

one can arrive at a better solution

```
echo $(basename "${PWD%/*}")/${PWD##*/}
```

where I say better because two fewer processes are spawned.

Anyone have a cute trick to avoid using `basename` at all?  This is for something run every shell prompt so it'd be nice to be as lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for p in /home/rhys/share/pkgconfig /home/rhys /home /; do
  [[ $p =~ .*/([^/]+/[^/]+)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || echo "$p"
done
```

As a function:

```
last2() { [[ $1 =~ .*/([^/]+/[^/]+)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || echo "$1"; }
```

Should work on `bash` >= 3.2

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using bash and awk:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)"/"$NF}' <<<"$PWD"
```

#### Edit

The previous one is not quite right, as it prints `/home` rather than just `home`. Maybe you can live with that. If not, this one works fully:

```
awk -F'/' '{if (NF==2 && $2) {$0=$2} else {$0=$(NF-1)"/"$NF}}1' <<<"$PWD"
```

Testing it out:

```
awk -F'/' '{if (NF==2 && $2) {$0=$2} else {$0=$(NF-1)"/"$NF}}1' <<EOF
/home/rhys/share/pkgconfig
/home/rhys
/home
/
EOF
```

Output:

```
share/pkgconfig
home/rhys
home
/
```

Comment: It's pretty, but it still spawns one process.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will work in `bash` 4 or later:

```
trim () (
  IFS=/
  read -a c <<< "$1"
  unset c[0]
  fragment="${c[*]: -2:2}"
  echo "${fragment:-/}"
)

for p in /home/rhys/share/pkgconfig /home/rhys /home /; do
  trim "$p"
done

share/pkgconfig
home/rhys
home
/
```

Comment: Why is `IFS` set in two places? Could you not just move `IFS=/` to the top of the function?

Comment: I was playing around with different ideas about what should go in the subshell, and didn't clean up once I settled on making the entire function body a subshell :)